# Routing ipv4 traffic to ipv6 on windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, ipv6, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running some services on WSL2 which only seems to support listening on ipv6 interface on the host side. This means everything outside WSL trying to connect to a WSL2 service on 127.0.0.1 is failing. Is there a way in Windows to route all 127.0.0.1:X traffic to [::]:X?

Comment: Stop using 127.0.0.1 and use localhost.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not always an option. I'm dealing with some services which require an ip address and it needs to be v4.

Comment: Gawd, it's amazing some app developers are still stuck in the distant past. This has been the way to do it since Vista/2008. Anyway, I haven't played with WSL but on real Linux, by default an IPv6 listener will also listen on IPv4, so if their emulation is good enough, it should just work even though the services you're dealing with are stupid.

Comment: WSL2 does something with networking and the internal network is only available as v6 to the outside world. Inside, both 6 and 4 work just fine.

Comment: Well, you said it was 127.0.0.1, that's the local host. The outside world doesn't matter. Or are you actually dealing with something else?

Comment: Sorry, bad choice of words. By outside world I meant outside WSL, which means local on windows host.

Comment: It may also be that the service itself has chosen not to accept IPv4 connections. You didn't name the service, so it's impossible for the rest of us to check on this possibility.

Comment: So it looks like that on WSL 2, access via `localhost` from Windows apps is just a hack and the WSL 2 app should be accessible via the WSL 2 virtual IP address. Use `ip a s eth0` to see what that address is.

Comment: Seems like you're right - wsl should be accessed via the virtual ip, rather than 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

You must wait seem so [Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#ipv6-access)

> WSL 2 distributions currently cannot reach IPv6-only addresses. We are
> working on adding this feature.

Comment: It's the other way around - I can reach inside via v6 but not v4.

Comment: it doesn't necessarily means it will work from the other side / inside, because it's (for now) unsupported in WSL2 and that's what you're using.

Comment: Ipv6 works - v4 doesn't. That quote doesn't apply for this case.

Comment: sound like you've tried [netsh proxy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy) and it didn't work, am I right? Afaik recently was problem to run docker and hyper-v on same Windows 10 machine in the same time  (MS fixed it about 6 months ago) and looks very similar to me what you're describing, but with network stack not virtualization vs/and containers.